# Play media files located in assets folder

Tags: android, assets, android-mediaplayer

I currently have a set of media files in the raw folder of the android project that are loaded quickly and played when called using the mediaplayer class. I need to add more variations of these files and categorize them into folders, but apparently the raw folder does not support folders. Would I be able to quickly load these files from the assets folder and play them with mediaplayer? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've this method that returns the all files by extension in a folder inside asset folder:

```
public static String[] getAllFilesInAssetByExtension(Context context, String path, String extension){
        Assert.assertNotNull(context);

        try {
            String[] files = context.getAssets().list(path);

            if(StringHelper.isNullOrEmpty(extension)){
                return files;
            }

            List<String> filesWithExtension = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(String file : files){
                if(file.endsWith(extension)){
                    filesWithExtension.add(file);
                }
            }

            return filesWithExtension.toArray(new String[filesWithExtension.size()]);  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

if you call it using:

```
getAllFilesInAssetByExtension(yourcontext, "", ".mp3");
```

this will return all my mp3 files in the root of assets folder.

if you call it using:

```
getAllFilesInAssetByExtension(yourcontext, "somefolder", ".mp3");
```

this will search in "somefolder" for mp3 files

Now that you have list all files to open you will need this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("myfile");
```

To play the file just do:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
long end = descriptor.getLength();

player.setDataSource(this.descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
player.prepare();

player.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
player.start();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that can play mediafiles from your asset folder. And you can use it with smth like `play(this,"sounds/1/sound.mp3");`

```
private void play(Context context, String file) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(file);
        meidaPlayer.setDataSource(
                afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                afd.getStartOffset(),
                afd.getLength()
            );
        afd.close();
        meidaPlayer.prepare();
        meidaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your mp3 files at : res/raw folder as myringtone.mp3 or as your wish.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.myringtone);
mediaPlayer.start();
```