# Playing music from List View

Tags: android, listview, media-player

Hi i have list and i have local music files . i want to play my music files when i click my list items .
heres my onclick list item looks :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            switch( position )
            {
               case 0:  
                   v.contentEquals("file:///android_asset/disco.mp3");
                   playSound(v);
               case 1:
                  v.contentEquals("file:///android_asset/disco.mp3");
                   playSound(v); 
                       break;
            };

        }
```

and heres my media player looks like :

```
private void playSound(String v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(v);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
```

when i click on list items program freezes  and force closed .
what should i do ?

logcatoutput

> 01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at com.hmomeni.customlistview.MainActivity$11.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:113)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1519)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3291)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4340)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>   01-11 23:19:19.191: E/AndroidRuntime(4811):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What you should do is paste your stack trace and show us your errors. Thank You

Comment: maybe caused by file addressing can you post your Log dada?

Comment: Line 113th may contain a variable not initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"v" is a normal string? if so, since it's immutable, you cannot change it via a function using :

```
v.contentEquals("file:///android_asset/disco.mp3");
```

you are supposed to set it using the normal "="  :

```
v="file:///android_asset/disco.mp3";
```

Comment: do you initialize "mp" before calling "playSound" ?

Comment: and yes its normal string . any other methods to play number of songs ? my list has ten items and then diffrent song how should i adreess them ?

Comment: first you need to handle the exception no? anyway, you should have them in an array instead of addressing each of the items (imagine what you would do with 1000 songs...) . maybe use the adapter of your list to get to the item that was selected (using "getItem()"), and get its path ?

Comment: for playing a file in the assets folder, maybe you should check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8107056/878126

Comment: btw, in order to find the cause of the bug, you can double click the exception on the logcat and see where it goes. you can also put a breakpoint on the beginning of the function (double click on the left of the start of the line), debug (click the button that looks like a bug), and then do a step by step over the lines till you see what's going on (using F5, F6, F7 and F8, each does a different kind of stepping).

Comment: @Soheyl i don't understand. what was the problem exactly and which of the things i've written helped you?

Comment: i used getitem and it works .tnx and my adapter had problems too.

Comment: @Soheyl so it didn't have anything to do with the string not being updated?