# Reading music from asset folder

Tags: java, android

My project is list of music that user can set as ringtone.
All of my music is located in raw and it works correctly and also my ringtone name is a text in raw "zeallist".
My problem is that how to put my music in asset folder.

Here is my code that play music from raw:

```
  public ArrayList<SongInfo> getAllSong(Context context) {
    ArrayList<SongInfo> listSong = new ArrayList<SongInfo>();
    RingtonesSharedPreferences pref = new RingtonesSharedPreferences(
            context);
    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
        SongInfo info = new SongInfo();
        try {
            String name = fields[i].getName();           
            if (!name.equals("ringtones")) {   
                info.setFileName(name + ".mp3");
                info.setFavorite(pref.getString(info.getFileName()));
                int audioResource = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(name);
                info.setAudioResource(audioResource);
            }
            // info.setName(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        listSong.add(info);
    }
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.zeallist);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));   
    try {
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            listSong.get(i).setName(line);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listSong;
}
```

How to change this part of my code to read them from asset and return my listsong ?

Comment: maybe this link will helpfull : [check out this link ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106694/play-media-files-located-in-assets-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core part I have finished.Some details you need do yourself

```
  public ArrayList<SongInfo> getAllSong(Context context) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<SongInfo> listSong = new ArrayList<SongInfo>();
        RingtonesSharedPreferences pref = new RingtonesSharedPreferences(context);
            String[] files = context.getAssets().list("Your songs path");
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length - 1; i++) {
                SongInfo info = new SongInfo();
                    String name = files[i];
                    if (!name.equals("ringtones")) {
                        info.setFileName(name + ".mp3");
                        info.setFavorite(pref.getString(info.getFileName()));
                    /*    int audioResource = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(name);
                        info.setAudioResource(audioResource);*/  //fileName is enough to you
                    }
                    // info.setName(name);
                listSong.add(info);
            }
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("Your zeallist path");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                int i = 0;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    listSong.get(i).setName(line);
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return listSong;
    }
```

When you want to play corresponding music, you could do like this

```
  public void play(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, Context context, String musicName) throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(musicName);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem .

Comment: now I can read my music from assets correctly But when I want to play , I got error from this line . AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(musicName);

Comment: That line i copy from my programe , It works on my programe. so i need to know the error log that line caused .but i can't find the log your post .

Comment: Check whether the context you pass is null .  if  context.getAssets().list("Your songs path") works , it make no sense context.getAssets().openFd(musicName) throw NullPointerException. or you pass wrong musicname .check the music's path and name is correct

Comment: I checked the code and I realized that my problem is in this line, here I need an int to play my music.this line-->int audioResource = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(name);
                        info.setAudioResource(audioResource);

Comment: Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.

However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ are not given a resource ID, so you can read them only using AssetManager.    If you want to put your music file in assets ,you must use AssetManager to open them .

Comment: here AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(musicName); when I give one of my name of music manually, it works and play but I dont know how to fill this openFd(musicName) , my musicName

Comment: Didn't you save your music name in SongInfo?   info.setFileName(name + ".mp3");   Oh,I see . you'd better change it to info.setFileName(name);

Comment: You mean this--> AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(info.getFileName()); I MUST fill this value,my musicname is null

Comment: Of course , your intent  that traverse assets directory is to get all music files . so you 'd better store all of their name  and use their name  when you want to  play music .

Comment: I read name of them from asset and save them in this string  String name = files[i];, when i play nothing is palying

Comment: You gave one of your name of music manually and it works .So it must be file name wrong . Did you print file's name and check whether it is right ? You'd better think this kind of question carefully .

Comment: finally I found the solution ,Thnx for you attention

Answer (score 0):

Right click on res folder and Create new folder called raw. Now copy paste few .MP3 files inside it. Check those links for better understanding.

[link1](https://acadgild.com/blog/load-mp3-resource-raw-folder/)

[link2](http://deadmango.com/index.php/archives/1623)

**From Assest folder**

```
public void playBeep() {
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("mysong.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        mp.prepare();
        mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please take a look at my code , here I do want media player , I must change this part of my code just .  Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields(); and int audioResource = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(name);

Answer (score 0):

You can read file from asset using `AssetManager`

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

Note that this file is String array. So don't forget to initialize new file for each element of the array before iterating over it.